# Mapping Models into Controller is right?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a question which is blowing my mind nowadays.
First I have 4 Solution which is BL, DAL, DTO and MVC in my project and the project about content management systems. 
And also I am working with Store Procedures on server side.

What is the best apporach about models? Should I have dto and olsa viewmodel or just dto?

Also if I use two models, where is the best place to mapping them? ( Inside controller or BI)?

Answer (score 2):

DTO's serve an entire other purpose than ViewModels. Whereas DTO's are made to transfer data between services and clients, are ViewModels made to pass data from Controllers to Views.

You probably don't want to edit your DTO if you edit your View in such a way that you need more data, so this is the place where ViewModels come in handy. So yes, having ViewModels as well would make sense. And since your MVC project is the only project using ViewModels, it would sound logic not to bother the Business Logic with them.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping is a necessary evil if you want to keep a clean separation between your layers.  In your scenario, it seems you want to map the data returned from the database and the data returned from your controllers.  There are no absolute rules about where and how mappings should occur.

I would map your database data into DTOs in your BL.  So, you get the data from the DL, apply the business logic and then transfer it.  You only need to map the data that you need to transfer into the DTO.  At this point your controllers have received the DTOs and need to return some stuff to the views.

Your controllers will map the DTOs to the view-models.  Again, this doesn't need to be a 1-to-1 mapping.  Many times the view-models will contain more or less information - UI specific logic for example.

Remember, what you're trying to accomplish is not an exercise in mapping.  Different layers have different needs and this is why we map and the mappings shouldn't primarily be 1-to-1.

Use Automapper for all your mapping needs.  Use the Profile feature to separate the mapping logic.  Then, all you need to do is a one-liner in you controllers and BL classes - Mapper.Map...

Comment: I am not sure that automapper will provide 1-1 mapping or it will map what I want?

Comment: @onurcan...It will map what you want.  It will take a little coding, but it's very powerful

Comment: Thank you very much. It will make what I want easier

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything but entities and view models for a website. A DTO may come in handy for working with other services or applications, but it's completely superfluous for a web application. You should pull the entities out of your database in your DAL, and then map them to/from view models in your MVC project. That's it.

As to where you should do this exactly in your MVC project. That's sort of up to you. Ultimately, it's the job of the controller to wire up everything for the view. That includes things like fetching stuff from the database, creating view models, etc. However, that doesn't mean that the actual specific code for doing these things should live there. You're DAL is obviously the best place for querying the database, but your controller would utilize your DAL to request what it needs. The same applies to your view models. You may choose to set up the mapping code wherever you like, but your controller will ultimately be what calls into that to make it happen.